# Is there a difference between must and may in limiting phrases?

Tags: meaning

I have a question about term of use in online contracts

I see often the term
" you may only have one account"

is it as stronger as 
"you must only have one account"?

is it possible consider " you may only have one account" more like a suggestion than a strict obligation?

Comment: 'May' in this context appears to mean 'are permitted to', so I do not think it can be interpreted as a suggestion.

Comment: related: [What is the difference between 'can', 'could', 'may' and 'might'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/99957/what-is-the-difference-between-can-could-may-and-might) and [What is the difference between “have to”, “must”, and “should”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123937/what-is-the-difference-between-have-to-must-and-should)

Comment: Also related, very closely: [“May not” — no choice vs. mere restriction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19549/may-not-no-choice-vs-mere-restriction)

Comment: It depends on who's speaking.  If it's your mother they mean the same thing.

Comment: Have you checked the two words in a good dictionary?

Comment: Don't say *_as stronger as_. Either say _stronger than_ or _as strong as_.They're not the same, but this is a question and they'll both get the same answer. Don't say *_I see often the phrase_; it should be _I often see_. You can't put adverbs between verb and object.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are systematically ambiguous.
They each contain a modal auxiliary (*must, may*) **and** a negative [quantifier](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96324/15299) (*only*).
This mix of operators in one proposition inevitably produces ambiguity.
Further, *only* is the kind of quantifier that [binds a focus](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55314/15299). (1) below is ambiguous between (2) and (3), with different focus.

1. He only [drinks dark beer on Tuesdays].
2. He drinks **only [dark beer]** on Tuesdays.
3. He drinks dark beer **[on Tuesdays] only**.

This is because words that bind a focus can appear right before the focus word (or right after, especially at the end of the sentence), **or** they can appear right before any constituent phrase or clause that contains the focus, so (1) could refer to either (2) or (3), or to their combination, which is yet another phrase.

That's just one of the complexities of *only*. The modals add several other dimensions.

With generic *you* (i.e, the reader) as a subject, *may only have one account* is **deontic** (i.e, it refers to social obligation/permission, not logical necessity/possibility). And it means that you must not have more than one account. It does not mean that you must have an account at all; just no more than one.

*Must only have one account*, is also deontic; however, it requires that you have no more than one account, and **also** requires that you have an account.

So they're not quite the same. I should add that the distinction is minuscule, and probably limited to this particular context and construction type. Like I said, the phenomenon is much more complex semantically than it may appear.

Answer (score 0):

No, "you may only have only one account" is **not** merely a suggestion.  It is the preferred way to say this.  It rules out the possibility of having two or more accounts.

"You must have only one account" would rule out the possibility of having no account at all.

Answer (score 0):

**must v. may**

must  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/must):

- 1. To be obliged or required by morality, law, or custom:
  2. To be compelled, as by a physical necessity or requirement:
  3. Used to express a command or admonition:
  4. To be determined to; have as a fixed resolve; inevitability or certainty; logical probability or presumptive certainty

and

**may** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/may)

- 1. *To be allowed or permitted to*:
  2. Used to express possibility or probability:
  3. Used to express a desire or fervent wish:
  4. Used to express contingency, purpose,

Some overlap, some confusion, but in a contract:  " you may only have one account" is not a suggestion. *If you choose to enter* into this contract you will (may) have one account.

Comment: @Mari-LouA edited to attempt to correct 'oversimplied and mistaken'.

Answer (score 0):

If the "only" is removed from these sentences: 
"You may have one account" - permission.
"You must have one account" - obligation.
If "only" is added, 
You may only have one account = You must not have more than one account.
The "must" is already implied in the sentence.